# What does this regular expression do?

Tags: scripting, rpm

I have been provided a %post script inside a spec file to edit a config file (called foo). 
I have ben tasked with writing another, almost identical script to edit a file called 'bar'.

While my solution for 'bar' technically works, it is dramatically different semantically. The custodian is requesting I rewrite it for consistency.

foo.groovy before

```
messageQueue.secretKey = "<ENTER-KEY-HERE>"
```

foo.groovy after

```
messageQueue.secretKey = "y775hUYKR1Bm4gUWNRbzqg65"
```

The script given me is the following:

```
%define oauth_client_Secret \
echo "  Setting the message queue secret key..." \
MESSAGEQUEUESECRETKEY=`dd if=/dev/urandom count=16 bs=1 2>/dev/null | base64` \
for config_file in `find /opt/foo/etc -name *.groovy` \
do \
sed -i -e "/messageQueue.secretKey/ { " \\\
        -e "    s?^//\s*??" \\\
        -e "    s?<ENTER-KEY-HERE>?${MESSAGEQUEUESECRETKEY}?" \\\
        -e "}" \\\
    ${config_file} \
done
```

What I am trying to figure out:

1. What does this regex do? `s?^//\s*??"` I assume it is looking for an equals sign?
2. What is the purpose of the trailing slashes ? `\\\`
3. Why did the previous author surround the expression in brackets `{ }` ?

---

For reference, here is my script (for bar), that I am trying to rewrite to match the above script (for foo)

bar.groovy before

```
clientSecret:"<ENTER-CLIENTSECRET-HERE>",
```

bar.groovy after

```
clientSecret:"4gUWNRbzqg65y775hUYKR1Bm",
```

bar script

```
%define oauth_client_Secret \
echo "  Generating oauth clientSecret..." \
MESSAGEQUEUESECRETKEY=`dd if=/dev/urandom count=16 bs=1 2>/dev/null | base64` \
for config_file in `find /opt/bar/etc -name *.groovy` \
do \
sed -i "s/<ENTER-CLIENTSECRET-HERE>/${MESSAGEQUEUESECRETKEY}/g" ${config_file} \
done
```

Answer (score 2):

On any line containing the string `messageQueue.secretKey` it removes the string `//` and any spaces that follow if it exists at the start of the line and replaces the first occurrence of `<ENTER-KEY-HERE>` with the contents of the shell variable `${MESSAGEQUEUESECRETKEY}`. The `{` curlies confine the removals/replacements to *only* lines containing the string `messageQueue.secretKey`. These operations are performed on the file referenced by the shell variable `${config_file}.`

The `\\\`backslashes continue the statement into one long line - escaping the immediately following `\n`ewline character when the script is read in by the shell. Three are necessary because those are contained within `"` double-quotes and the backslash escapes itself in that context. So the shell gets one escaped newline and `sed` gets one escaped newline. Though, while I don't know about the shell in this context, I don't believe `sed` would care if the newlines were not escaped at all anyway.

Answer (score 1):

1. What does this regex do? `s?^//\s*??"`

Remove the `//` and any spaces following from the line start on lines that contain messageQueue.secretKey with:

- the question mark `?` as the pattern delimiter
- `^` matches the beginning of a line
- `//` matches exactly that (on a side note that is the reason to use the question mark as the pattern delimiter instead of the more common `/` which prevents quite a bit of escaping because otherwise the regex would be `s/^\/\/\s*//`
- `\s*` is GNU sed specific to match or or more whitespace <kbd>space</kbd> and/or <kbd>Tab</kbd> ; POSIX sed would use `[:space:]`

And @mikeserv has just posted an even more comprehensive answer...

Comment: In truth, it was posted before this, but yours has pretty bullets, so I voted for it. More importantly though - you point out the GNU specific syntax, which also applies to `-i`.

Comment: :) same here. Got somewhat distracted halfway through and then when I got back to it I noticed your answer had popped up but didn't want to discard what I had.

Comment: I'm glad you didn't.